# I am looking for an idiom that describes people requesting something which they don't really need

Tags: expressions

Let me describe the context:

I am at an infertility treatment clinic. A 6-year-old boy is lost and crying. A clinic user sitting next to me nags in my native language. What she says literally means is that people coming to this clinic don't really need a baby. Then she adds that "they either have a daughter and wants a son or they have come for a second one. If God only gives us one, we don't have any requests".

Comment: "... from a position of (relative) luxury"?

Comment: Rephrasing a [British idiom](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carry-take-coals-to-newcastle?a=british), it would be like _Newcastle is asking for coal_...

Comment: *they're being greedy* ?

Comment: *Gilding the lily* ?

Comment: "redundant"  or "its a bonus" ?

Answer (score 1):

***[Icing on the cake](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/icing+on+the+cake)***

> Fig. an extra enhancement

Freedictionary.com

This doesn't fit perfectly what you're after, though, because it doesn't include the negative, critical attitude you conveyed in your example.

> They're doing a fertility treatment to try to have a second baby, but since they already have one, it seems like it would just be icing on the cake.

You could also just combine some words to convey the idea, without it being an existing idiom, for example

> If their basic needs are already amply satisfied, but they still want *more*, then it looks like they're just being greedy.

You could also say that the would-be second time around parents are being *selfish*.  (I don't agree -- I'm just trying to help you express the various relevant ideas.)